# Error message : Windows service can not start on your local machine windows 7 OS

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am very new to windows service. I want same functionality in my windows service as it is in my asp.net web application.

It haven't any UI.

I am briefing my web application here so according to that you can guide me how to do it in windows service.

1. Retrieving very Big image from **IMAGE** folder which resides in my web application according to certain condition.
2. Resize those image and store it into database.
3. Retrive resized images stored in database and store it into server folder called **Large** and again resize that image in 3 more different size and save into their three respective size folders called **List**, **Mini**,**Thumb** on server.

Now i want to build windows service with same functionality and it run on server after every 15 mins.

Hope now i am more clear. please help me in this regards.

my web application code is working fin. but i don't know where to put this code in my windows service as I am very new to windows service.

I tried to put that code **onstart** and also **oncontinue** method but that time service not allowed to start. It gives error message this service can not start on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

`OnStart` must complete within a 30 (??? iirc) second timeout. I'd suggest spinning off a Thread in `OnStart` to do the work so that `OnStart` completes immediately.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        (new Thread(() => DoLongRunningStartupWork()){IsBackground = true})
           .Start();

    }

    void DoLongRunningStartupWork()
    {
        //actual startup code
    }
```

Comment: @spender.. I tried to do it suggested above both way it install service but when i start service from service panel it gives error "Windows could not start the XYZ service on Local computer Error 1053: The service didnt respond to start or control request in timely fashion"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a method that is called from within the `OnStart` method.  The `OnStart` method is there purely for configuring the service when it starts up.  You'll want something like:

```
void OnStart()
{
    DoSomething();
}

void DoSomething()
{
     // Your code here
}
```

I've seen people use `Thread`s in order to start there Windows Service and get then the `Thread` does the work that is required.

Comment: I tried to do it both way it install service but when i start service from service panel it gives error "Windows could not start the XYZ service on Local computer Error 1053: The service didnt respond to start or control request in timely fashion"

Comment: Are you just reinstalling the service each time?  Or are you uninstalling and reinstalling?